# Why I Cannot Change Data In Angular JS Service.js After executing function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I've got this service i use for my 2 controller (each one in different html page). When I clicked the function it cannot change the default variable I've set earlier

Service

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
    .service('ContentSize', function() {
        var triggers = [{
            count: 1
        }];
        var counters = [{
            index: 0
        }, {
            index: 1
        }, {
            index: 2
        }];
        return {
            getCounters: function() {
                return counters;
            },
            getCounter: function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
                    if (counters[i].index = triggers[0].count) {
                        return [counters[i].index];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            },
            setIndex: function(counter) {
                triggers[0].count = counter;
                console.log(triggers[0].count);
            },
            getIndex: function() {
                return triggers[0].count;
            }
        };
    });
```

the console.log i put inside the function works well, but when I put it outside the return part It doesn't even show the default triggers[0].count. Anyone can help me understand the problem ?

```
//This is the 1st controller :
.controller('cat1Controller' , function($scope, ContentSize) {

    //Text Size Declaration for text in page
    $scope.textTriggers = [{count: 0, size:2}];

    $scope.Index = ContentSize.getIndex();
    if ($scope.Index == 0) {
        $scope.textTriggers = [{count: 0, size:2}];
        console.log('Default');
    } 
    else if ($scope.Index == 1) {
        $scope.textTriggers = [{count: 1, size:3}];
        console.log('Medium');
    }
    else {
        $scope.textTriggers = [{count: 2, size:4}];
        console.log('Large');
    }
})

//The2nd Contorller
.controller('ModalController', function($scope, $ionicModal, ContentSize) {
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/settingmodal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
  $scope.small = function (x) {
    ContentSize.setIndex(x);
  };
  $scope.medium = function (x) {
      ContentSize.setIndex(x);
  };
  $scope.large = function (x) {
    ContentSize.setIndex(x);
  };
});
```

Comment: Can we also see the code where you are calling your service methods. Also check if you are getting any console errors. And to put your code into the question simply paste the code select the code and press 'Ctrl + K'

Comment: @Yasser I've added the controller and for the error, none seen in the browser as I use it to develop my web

Comment: So it seems you are calling service's `setIndex` method from the `ModalController`, check the value `x` which you are passing. Is the control even reaching the service ?

Comment: @Yasser the value is passed and the log shows up the x value I use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the console.log() 'outside' of the return part of your service, then it *will* always only be called once: when the service is first initialised. That's because the code you put outside of the return is only executed upon service instantiation, which only ever happens once (Angular services are singletons).

The functions that you return from the service (i.e. getCounters(), getCounter(), setIndex() and getIndex()) are properties of the service object you're returning. These effectively act as your service's API, and are 'public' functions that your controllers can freely call.

As such, the code within any of these functions gets called whenever a controller makes a call to one of them, and so a console.log() within one of these functions will be executed every time the function is called.

But the code *outside* of this returned service object only gets called once, which is why a console.log() declared outside of the return call is also only called once.

Comment: Thx @Untangled, now I understand more.